# I am using ubuntu 12.04.presently I am having a booting problem relating busybox v1.18.5 and initramfs prompt

Tags: boot

```
mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/02bc41cc-1e21-4700-a179-be2805a658c4 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
BusyBox v1.18. (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(initramfs)
```

Please suggest a way out. I am dual booting with windows 7 and I have many photos which I can not afford to lose.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have modified your partitioning scheme outside ubuntu. what you need to do is live boot some linux distribution and open gparted. then you would find UUIDs for all the disk drives. Open /etc/fstab of your installed linux (not live boot but your crashed linux system). There you would find a table showing drive partition UUID and mount point. check for any UUIDs which are invalid (i.e there is a UUID shown in fstab but there is no drive with that UUID shown in gparted) and replace the UUIDs of each partition with the new ones.

Comment: BTW, you will not loose any data. in worst case scenario you can simply copy those photos to an external drive and reinstall ubuntu